# Chrome on OS X Yosemite Producing Garbled Graphics

Tags: macos, google-chrome, graphics

A couple of weeks ago Chrome started producing unusably garbled graphics for me, under OS X Yosemite 10.10.5.

It's perhaps easier to show than to tell.  For instance, Gmail looks like this:

[image]

...seems like it may be some sort of interlacing glitch, as if I adjust the window size I can get vaguely coherent things to display, such as:

[image]

I haven't changed any settings in Chrome; the issue seemed to appear at random.  Neither rebooting the computer nor restarting Chrome makes any difference.  Other browsers (Safari, Firefox) work fine, as does every other app on the machine.  The problem seems to be specific to Chrome.

Is there anything I can do to get Chrome usable again?

Edit - My chrome version is:

[image]

I'm pretty sure that says "46.0.2490.71".

Comment: Could you update the question with what kind of Mac you use, and version of Chrome you have installed?

Comment: @agentroadkill - Added the Chrome version.  Not sure what you mean by "kind" of Mac.  It's the kind that an employer might provide their employees; a relatively modern x86 64-bit model, in terms of CPU architecture.

Comment: To find out the Mac model, go to the Apple menu on top left, select "About this Mac" and then take the line right about the one describing the CPU.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe this was related to Chrome's hardware video acceleration feature, and has been fixed. I had the [same issue](http://displaylink.org/forum/showthread.php?p=78820#post78820) with an external monitor attached to a USB DisplayLink adapter. After updating to Chrome 46.0.2490.80, the bug [(#527556)](https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=527556) was resolved.

Comment: Thanks, allowing Chrome to update did the trick.  Slightly complicated by the fact that I _could not see anything_ on the 'About Google Chrome' tab to know if/when the update was ready.  However I found that just letting it sit on the 'About' tab for several minutes and then quitting/restarting it allowed the update to install and did the trick in terms of fixing the browser UI.

Answer (score 0):

I've seen this too on 2 of my systems. Went away by itself not sure how or why, maybe a Chrome update.